# cvFit() cross-validation error for nls model: "Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, cross-validation, nls, nonlinear-functions

I have this `nls()` model running pretty smoothly, and I want to be able to do a cross-validation using the `cvTools` package, but I get this error when I run the `cvFit()` function:

> Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

RStudio automatically opens the debugger, and I get this in the source viewer:

```
function (x, env = parent.frame(), ...) 
{
    notAtomic <- !is.atomic(x)
    notnull <- function(z) notAtomic && !is.null(z)
    if (notnull(x$formula)) #this part is hightlited in the source viewer for some reason
        eval(x$formula)
    else if (notnull(x$terms)) {
        z <- x$terms
        oldClass(z) <- "formula"
        z
    }
    else if (notnull(x$call$formula)) 
        eval(x$call$formula)
    else if (!is.null(attr(x, "formula"))) 
        attr(x, "formula")
    else {
        form <- switch(mode(x), `NULL` = structure(NULL, class = "formula"), 
            character = formula(eval(parse(text = x)[[1L]])), 
            call = eval(x), stop("invalid formula"))
        environment(form) <- env
        form
    }
}
```

I have included an extract of my dataframe in the following link in the .csv format: https://www.sendspace.com/file/ec1aoa

And here is the code I used:

```
fctmod<-function(x,y,z){
  resultat<-(1+x*((z-mean(z))/mean(z))+y*((z-mean(z))/mean(z))^2)
  return(resultat)
}

fctmodlin<-function(x,z){
  resultat<-(1+x*((z-mean(z))/mean(z)))
  return(resultat)
}

nlscut<- nls(BAI ~ (a*(B_A)^(b))*
                         fctmodlin(c,PPT.an)*
                         fctmod(e,f,maxTmax.an)*
                         fctmod(g,h,GPautre),
                       start = list(a = 1.14338, b = 0.504549,c=0, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0),
                       data = datacut,
                       weights= wfct(DHPc))

library(cvTools)
testcut<-cvFit(nlscut, data=datacut,y=datacut$BAI,cost=mspe,K=10,R=1,seed=1234)
```

Comment: Check for typoes in your variable names and that you have given the formula to the function properly. Usually this error occurs when R cannot find one or more of the variables that you want the function to use in the formula.

Comment: @Teemu Daniel Laajala: Nope, there is no typo in the function or the variables, it's a fairly simple call at that...

Comment: Hmm, it's really hard to guess where the problem lies when there is no reproducible example available. I'm guessing that maybe the object you provide for the function as parameter 'x' isn't what it expects. Perhaps there is no $formula-slot defined in x then, which it is trying to access. Alternatively, maybe the variables that the formula tries to call are not accessible by the function environment. A simple comparison in calls (first prints NULL, second the formula): fun <- function(x) print(x$formula); fun(Response ~ Covariate); ex <- list(); ex$formula <- Response ~ Covariate; fun(ex)

Comment: I have included a working example, that I have tested as well: still the same problem. If you have a mind to check it out, I'd be grateful!